# Reading file from AVD sd card and displaying text view

Tags: android, textview, android-virtual-device, filereader

I have a text file that has this information

Casino Canberra;21 Binara Street, Canberra ACT, 2601;Canberra Casino is a casino located in Civic in the central part of the Australian capital city of Canberra. The Casino is relatively small compared with other casinos in Australia.;(02) 6257 7074;www.canberracasino.com.au

National Museum of Canberra;Parkes Place, Canberra ACT, 2601;The National Museum of Australia explores the land, nation and people of Australia. Open 9am - 5pm every day except Christmas Day. General admission free.;(02) 6240 6411;www.nga.gov.au

which is stored in the sdcard

after this i retrieve the values using this method

```
package au.edu.canberra.g30813706;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Environment;


public class FileReader extends Activity{{

    ArrayList<read> sInfo = new ArrayList<read>();
    ArrayList<String> sLines = new ArrayList<String>();
    String line;
    String[] saLineElements;
String txtName = "AccomodationTxt.txt";
File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
File path = new File(root, "CanberraTourism/" + txtName);

try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (
                        new InputStreamReader(
                        new FileInputStream(path)));

    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        sLines.add(line);
        //The information is split into segments and stored into the array
        saLineElements = line.split(";");
        //for (int i = 0; i < saLineElements.length; i++) 
            //  sInfo.add(new read(saLineElements[i]));
        sInfo.add(new read(saLineElements[0], saLineElements[1], saLineElements[3], saLineElements[4], saLineElements[5]));     
    }
     br.close();
} 
catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.err.println("FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
} 
catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}}
}
```

But i also have and object class to store each individual item into

```
package au.edu.canberra.g30813706;

public class read {

    public String name;
    public String address;
    public String info; 
    public String phone;
    public String www;


    public read (String name, String address, String info, String phone, String www)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.info = info;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.www = www;
    }

}
```

The only issue im having is trying to display the information in a text view which i have no idea how to call the values i need

This is where im trying to insert it

```
package au.edu.canberra.g30813706;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import au.edu.canberra.g30813706.FileReader;
import au.edu.canberra.g30813706.read;

public class Accommodation_info  extends Activity{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.accommodation_layout);


    }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look into using the Application class.  You can think of Application as a GUI-less activity which works like the model in a program following the MVC pattern.  You can put all of your read objects into a data structure in your Application and then access them with accessors and mutators of your own design.

Take a look at this official [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html).

As your code stands, you can only access your instances of read by obtaining a reference to your FileReader class, but your two activities are separate entities.  You'd have to do something like this:

```
// This is the main activity and should be launched first
// Check your manifest to make sure it launches with this activity

package au.edu.canberra.g30813706;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import au.edu.canberra.g30813706.FileReader;
import au.edu.canberra.g30813706.read;

public class Accommodation_info  extends Activity
{
    // Declare the file reader so you'll have a reference

    FileReader reader;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.accommodation_layout);

    // Instantiate the file reader

    reader = new FileReader();

    // Now you can access the array inside FileReader

    // obviously, you need to have a text view called my_textView defined in the
    // layout file associated with this activity

    TextView myTextView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.my_textView);
    // displays the first element in FileReader's array list
    myTextView.setText((String)reader.get(0));
    }}
```

At the moment, you might be in a bit deep for your current understanding of Android and/or Java.  I would encourage you to follow as many code examples as possible, get comfortable with Android and then go back to your project when you have a little more experience.